Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser error when running tests with Jest and external dependency in a React project
I'm encountering an error when running Jest tests that involve an internal package built with React and Webpack. This issue only arises in the Jest testing environment and does not occur when running the code in Storybook or in the application directly.
The error specifically reads:
Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser
This internal package is bundled with Webpack and provides various components and theme configurations for the project. It appears that Jest, using jsdom, doesn’t handle publicPath correctly under these conditions, which causes this error.
Here are the configs of my project:
jest.config.ts
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!src/**/*.d.ts',
    '!src/index.tsx',
    '!src/constants/**/*',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: 'output/coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    './src/*/*.types.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/index.tsx',
    './src/redux',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['clover'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/src/config/setupTests.ts',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': [
      '@swc/jest', {
        jsc: {
          transform: {
            react: {
              runtime: 'automatic',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    '\\.css$': 'jest-css-modules-transform',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', __dirname],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  snapshotFormat: {
    printBasicPrototype: true,
  },
  reporters: [
    'default',
    ['jest-junit', { outputDirectory: 'output', outputName: 'junit.xml' }],
  ],
};


package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js; js_status=$?; npm run lint:css; css_status=$?; [ $js_status -ne 0 ] || [ $css_status -ne 0 ] && exit 1 || exit 0",
    "lint:js": "npx eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "lint:js:fix": "npx eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --fix",
    "lint:css": "npx stylelint src/**/*.{css,scss} --aei",
    "lint:css:fix": "npx stylelint src/**/*.{css,scss} --fix",
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:coverage:html": "jest --coverage --coverageReporters=html",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "storybook:build": "storybook build -o dist/storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@this-is-the-package-but-its-internal": "1.2.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.15.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^8.3.6",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.3.6",
    "@swc/jest": "^0.2.27",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/pendo-io-browser": "^2.17.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.10.1",
    "i18next": "^23.3.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-css-modules-transform": "^4.4.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "msw": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "sass": "^1.64.1",
    "storybook": "^8.3.6",
    "storybook-react-i18next": "^3.1.7",
    "stylelint": "^14.11.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "output": "output/coverage/junit/junit.xml",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6"
  }
}


Environment
Node - v20.18.0
npm - 10.8.2
